# std::reduce with functor

Tags: c++, libstdc++

I tried to use `std::reduce` with a functor to calculate the number of characters in an array. GCC gives an error, while it compiles and works in MSVC. [link here](https://godbolt.org/z/hkGPT7)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::array arr{ "Mickey","Minnie","Jerry" };
    struct StringLength
    {
        auto operator()(const char* l, size_t r)
        {
            return strlen(l) + r;
        }
        auto operator()(size_t l, const char* r)
        {
            return l + strlen(r);
        }
        auto operator()(const char* l, const char* r)
        {
            return strlen(l) + strlen(r);
        }
        auto operator()(size_t l, size_t r)
        {
            return l + r;
        }
    };
    std::cout << std::reduce(arr.begin(), arr.end(), size_t{}, StringLength());
    // this ^ works in MSVC
}
```

GCC 10.1 error because important information should *not* be hidden behind a link:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/numeric:
In instantiation of '_Tp std::reduce(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation)
[with _InputIterator = const char**; _Tp = long unsigned int;
 _BinaryOperation = main()::StringLength]':

<source>:29:78:   required from here

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/numeric:263:21: error:
static assertion failed

  263 |       static_assert(is_convertible_v<value_type, _Tp>);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Looks like a gcc implementation bug. Also it accidentally works in gcc with this form: `std::reduce(std::execution::seq, arr.begin(), arr.end(), size_t{}, StringLength())`

Comment: @dewaffled I don't believe it is GCC bug. Because Clang gives the exact same error too.

Comment: ok, it's gcc libstdc++ bug, which is used by both gcc and clang on godbolt

Comment: You have to pass -stdlib=libc++ to Clang to make it actually use its own standard library on Godbolt. libstdc++ is GNU, libc++ is Clang, and the former is (for some reason) the global default on Godbolt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with **dewaffled** that this is a bug. The `libstdc++` [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-10/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/numeric#L255) of `std::reduce` looks like this:

```
template<typename InputIt, typename Tp, typename BinOp>
Tp reduce(InputIt first, InputIt last, Tp init, BinOp binary_op) {
    using value_type = typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;
    static_assert(is_invocable_r_v<Tp, BinOp&, Tp&, Tp&>);
    static_assert(is_convertible_v<value_type, Tp>);
    // ...
}
```

I wasn't able to find a requirement in [the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/reduce#5) that iterator's `value_type` has to be convertible into `Tp`. Moreover, this requirement is not necessary at all. If you remove that static assert, your code [will compile](https://godbolt.org/z/4DYUrT) just fine as it should.

**Update from GCC Bugzilla**

> Fixed for 9.5, 10.4 and 11.2.
> *Jonathan Wakely, 2021-06-18*

Comment: Submitted a report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95833